# how to write ocr array into word document in two coloumn matlab

Tags: matlab

i want save a scanned image text in to word file

```
I   = imread('1.jpg');
ocrResults     = ocr(I);
recognizedText = ocrResults.Text;
A  = recognizedText;
```

OCR text saver in cell array A
now i want print this cell array to word document in two column

With Regards

Sachin

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Have you looked at some of the file exchange submissions which writes text from MATLAB to word? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28558-control-ms-word-from-matlab

Comment: Thank u so much sir, ill try and update u soon